# Invalid initialization of non-const reference error while using boost::any_range

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I am writing a wrapper class that abstracts `std::map` `std::vector` and `boost::unordered_map`, to do this, I have defined separate container classes encapsulating each of the containers and an abstract base class that is common to these classes. Another class called `MyWrapper` overloads the `[]` operator and calls methods on a pointer of the abstract base class to get the values. It also creates a custom iterator from `boost::any_range` to iterate over the values. Here are my wrapper and base classes:

```
class MyClass{

    ContainerBase* cb;

//my custom iterator
    typedef boost::any_range<valT,boost::bidirectional_traversal_tag,
    valT&,std::ptrdiff_t>::iterator iterator;

// other methods and costructor
    const valT& operator[](size_t idx) const{
      return cb->getValueAtkey[idx];
    }

    iterator begin(){
     return cb->getbegin(); 
   }
}

class ContainerBase{
    //other methods
    virtual valT& getValueAtKey(size_t); //calls the underlying container's subscript 
    virtual MyClass::iterator getbegin();
}
```

I am using a templated map class and defining custom iterators on it using `boost::transform_iterator` to iterate through the key values as follows :

```
template<class MapType>     //std::map or boost::unordered_map 
class  MapDerived : public ContainerBase{        
 MapType cont;
 typedef boost::transform_iterator<value_extractor,typename MapType::iterator> value_iterator;
 MyClass::iterator getbegin(){ 
 return MyClasss::iterator(
 boost::make_transform_iterator<value_extractor,typename MapType::iterator>(cont.begin(),value_extractor()
          );      
 }    //similar function for end iterators 
}
```

I am getting the following error on compiling :

```
..boost/range/detail/any_iterator_wrapper.hpp:356: 
error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'valT&' from a temporary of type 'int'
```

preceded by a `instantiated from here` message at `return cb->getValueAtkey[idx];` inside `MyClass::operator[]()`

I am relatively new to boost and therefore cannot figure out where I am going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

At first sight, you only have a `const operator[]()`, and this calls a non-const `getValueAtKey()`. Try to either add a non-const `operator[]()` or adding a const `getValueAtKey()`.

Comment: I do have a non-const `operator[]` defined, I omitted it for the sake of brevity.

Comment: Then maybe the problem is in the code calling `operator[]()`. Could you show that code?